# Как выбрать нужные данные с json ? JS

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить значение track_name

```
$.ajax({
        url:'https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?format=jsonp&callback=%22track_name%22&q_lyrics=rap%20god&quorum_factor=1&apikey=7cf197d5a8683b4564113e32a0f08a6e',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        success: function (data){
            var f = data;
            var str = JSON.stringify(data.message.body.track_list);
            console.log(str);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму не угадал. но для справки можно оставить)

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify` - служит совсем другой цели, а не той, в качестве которой вы пытаетесь применить.

Достаточно просто взять данные из ответа и пробегаться по каждому треку в листе:

```js
$.ajax({
        url:'https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?format=jsonp&callback=%22track_name%22&q_lyrics=rap%20god&quorum_factor=1&apikey=7cf197d5a8683b4564113e32a0f08a6e',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        success: function (data){            
            var tracks = data.message.body.track_list;
            for (var idx in tracks) {
              console.log(tracks[idx].track.track_name);
            }            
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам требуется получить эти значения?

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url:'https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?format=jsonp&callback=%22track_name%22&q_lyrics=rap%20god&quorum_factor=1&apikey=7cf197d5a8683b4564113e32a0f08a6e',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSONP',
  success: function (data){
   data.message.body.track_list.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(obj.track.track_name) })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```